# Activity necessary for Widget?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I want to create a very simple widget in which I just have a single button and on click of that button, I want to execute some code. 
My question is, is it necessary to create an activity for this?
Or can I just extend AppWidgetProvider class and write execution code in onUpdate or onReceive method?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is necessary to create a class that extends activity to accomplish interaction with a button.

Answer (score 1):

In theory the provider is enough to handle appwidgets. In practice you will always need some kind of configuration, which is an Activity.

It is also very likely that the code to run, is too much for `onUpdate` and `onReceive`. At this moment you'll send Intent's out to some Actvity or Service.